# объехать vs. объездить for the sense of traveling all over a place?

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы, приставки

I'm familiar with how -ехать is used to form perfective motion verbs with directional prefixes: приехать, уехать, etc.; and how ездить can be used to form perfectives with non-directional prefixes: съездить, поездить.

My question: can об- – with the sense of 'going everywhere in a place' be considered directional and non-directional both? I'm wondering about examples like these:

> Я вот, например, хотел объехать весь земной шар.
>
> Она объехала почти весь мир.

...and these:

> Я был в Америке, Израиле, объездил всю Европу…
>
> Марио был агрономом, многолетним советником ООН по агрокультуре, объездил весь мир...

Is there a nuance I'm missing between объехать and объездить here, or can they be used more or less interchangeably?

Comment: I expect a significant part of natives won't pick up any additional meaning from use of one of the words or another. The word "объехать" just sounds better to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Объездить** is a bit *stronger* word, often belonging to the expression "**объездить** (изъездить, исколесить) **вдоль и поперёк**". Some dictionaries (like Ushakov's one) mark it as '*colloquial*' - anyway, **объездить** is less formal than the neutral **объехать** and usually means to visit those places *not just once*, to travel *intensively*, while объехать typically means '*to have been in every part* of some big region (maybe just once and even maybe by the end of one's life)'.

Comment: С этой постановкой Боурн объехал всю Европу, собирая полные залы зрителей, и вот теперь ее увидят москвичи. [Лебедина Любовь. ЛЮБИТЕ ТЕАТР? ПЛАТИТЕ! // Труд-7, 2007.05.30] 


С тех пор русская «Орестея» успела объездить всю Европу. [Лариса Юсипова. Ведомости (1996) // «Коммерсантъ-Daily», 1996.01.16]

Comment: Вы видите разницу?

Comment: Вижу. Во втором примере слово выбрано менее удачно: можно "успеть объехать" (побывав во всех подразумеваемых местах до текущего момента), а что такое "успеть объездить", знает только журналистка :) .

Answer (score 3):

The verbs "объехать" and "объездить" are **not absolute** synonyms,
and they are not completely interchangeable (imho).
There is a nuance (at least for me).

"Объехать" might mean "to visit different places in one travel":

> Филеас Фогг объехал весь мир за 80 дней.

"Объездить" means "to visit different places in separate travels,
with various directions":

> Я был в Америке, Израиле, объездил всю Европу…

means I had many separate voyages to different places in Europe,
returning home between them. Or at least I have stayed
in different places for substantial periods,
so I do not consider these travels as a single ride.

Comment: Он объехал всю Европу (за раз?) Ваше утверждение основано на чем?

Comment: I can't really feel the difference in the meaning.

Comment: Моё утверждение основано на моём понимании языка, не более того.
Я просто хотел указать на мелкий нюанс.
Фразу из вопроса "Я вот, например, хотел **объехать** весь земной шар" я мог бы понять двояко:
1. "Я хотел бы побывать в разных странах, не обязательно за одно путешествие, не обязательно за один год."
2. "Я хотел совершить кругосветное путешествие."
А фразу "Я вот, например, хотел **объездить** весь земной шар"
я бы понял только как 1, но не как 2.

Answer (score 1):

The verbs "объехать" and "объездить" are **absolute  synonyms** only in one meaning : " to visit different places" – побывать перебывать в разных местах.
In this meaning they are interchangeable.

> Мы объехали /объездили весь свет.

Источник:
**Малый академический словарь русского языка**

объездить
-езжу, -ездишь; прич. страд. прош. объезженный, -жен, -а, -о; сов., перех.

(несов. объезжать2).

**1**

**То же, что объехать (в 3 знач.)**

объехать
-еду, -едешь; повел. нет; сов., перех.

(несов. объезжать1).

1. также без доп.

Проехать вокруг кого-, чего-л.

{Вася:} Как разбойники раза два кругом острова объедут, и все атаман глядит в трубу подзорную. А. Островский, Горячее сердце.

2.

Проехать стороной, минуя кого-, что-л.

Объехать камень.

□

Я надеялся объехать слободу благополучно. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

Отец сердито упрекал кучера за то, что он вовремя не объехал задержавшую их партию {арестантов}. Л. Толстой, Воскресение.

**3.**

**Ездя, побывать всюду, во многих местах, странах.**

— Помнишь, ты хотел после книг объехать чужие края, чтоб лучше знать и любить свой? И. Гончаров, Обломов.

Answer (score 0):

To me there seems to be a stronger *continuity* aspect in *объездить* vs. *объехать*.

> Филеас Фогг объехал весь мир за 80 дней

would translate into

> Phileas Fogg has travelled around the world in eighty days

(as a single event) while

> Я [...] объездил всю Европу

would instead be

> I have/had been travelling around all Europe

(over multiple events).